# Right align Bootstrap4 Toggle buttons

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Probably has been asked before but didn't manage to find an answer.

I would simply like to right align the bootstrap4 toggle buttons.

```
<ul >
        <li>
            <label for="test1">Small Length Label</label>

            <input id="test1"  class="float-right" style="float: right" checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" />
        </li>



        <li>
            <label for="test2">Longer__ Length Label   </label>
            <input id="test2" style="float: right" checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" />

        </li>


        <li>
            <label for="test3">Longer_Longer_Longer Label </label>
            <input id="test3" style="float: right" checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox"  />
        </li>


    </ul>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r79wt265/) showing the current alignment.

I would like the toggle buttons to be on the same column no matter the text length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">`

Just wrap the elements inside the `li` like this:

```
<li>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <label for="test1">Small Length Label</label>
      <input id="test1" class="float-right" style="float: right" checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
 </li>
```

To have space between the text and input

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox for this. Just add the following classes to the `ul` element: `d-flex flex-column align-items-end`. And, optionally, a width of your choice.